# Android - Appcelerator : UI object with opacity 0 still "clickable"?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I'm converting an iOS app to be compatible with Android.

On iOS if i do this :

```
Ti.UI.createView({
    width : 10,
    height : 10,
    opacity : 0
});
```

---

```
Titanium SDK 5.5.1.G.A
```

The view is not clickable if the opacity property is set to 0 , but on Android it seems to be different. The view is still clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An opacity of 0 still means the object is there just not visible. It is probably native implementation how both platforms behave.

To disable click properly use the `touchEnabled` property

```
Ti.UI.createView({
    width : 10,
    height : 10,
    opacity : 0,
    touchEnabled: false
});
```

See the doc for more info: https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-touchEnabled

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i know this property, i was just hoping it was a bug, but it is the native behavior .. I'll have to change a lot of things then..